# Convert SQL to active record in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

```
SELECT *, SUM(`Relaxation_rating` + `Food_rating`) AS Ratings
GROUP BY CODE
ORDER BY Ratings DESC
FROM destinations
```

How do I convert this sql code to CctiveRecord in CodeIgniter?

I tried the following methods, but it did show any results.

```
$this->db->select("'(SELECT *, SUM(Relaxation_rating + Food_rating) FROM database GROUP BY CODE') AS Ratings", FALSE);
$this->db->get("database");
```

Comment: The [CodeIgniter user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) is pretty good. Try to use it.

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html look at select, select_sum

Comment: Your rewritten query is TOTALLY broken. You've got mismatched `'(` and `')` pairs, you're aliasing in the wrong place, blah blah blah.

Comment: The user of `$this->db-select` and `$this->db->get` doesn't make any sense either. Please read the user guide carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$data = $this->db->select('*, SUM(`Relaxation_rating` + `Food_rating`) AS Ratings', false)->group_by('CODE')->order_by('Ratings', 'desc')->get('destinations')->result_array();
```

Or,

```
$this->db->select('*, SUM(`Relaxation_rating` + `Food_rating`) AS Ratings', false)->group_by('CODE')->order_by('Ratings', 'desc')->get('destinations')->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$this->db->select('*, SUM(`Relaxation_rating` + `Food_rating`) AS Ratings');
$this->db->from('destinations');
$this->db->group_by('CODE');
$this->db->order_by('Ratings','desc');
$result = $this->db->get();
```